# Add a view programmatically in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I try to add a View at the same place of an other View in a ConstraintLayout but the added View don't get the LayoutParams of the other View.

The added View take place on the top|left of the container.

This is my code :

```
TextView cloneView = new TextView(getContext());
cloneView.setLayoutParams(otherView.getLayoutParams());
mainContainer.addView(cloneView);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add views to a ConstraintLayout you have to add the constraints using a ConstraintSet.

```
View v = findViewById(...);
ConstraintLayout cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(...);


ConstraintSet c = new ConstraintSet();
cl.addView(v);
int id = v.getId();

c.clone(cl);
c.connect(id, ConstraintSet.Top, otherViewIdAboveV, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
...
other constraints
...
c.applyTo(cl);
```

Comment: clone() - Copy the constraints from a layout, what if the layout is parent and have no constraints?

Comment: @PavelPoley I am not sure I understand the comment. The case is that the parent is a ConstraintLayout and by doing this you add Views to it with the corresponding contraints. If it doesn't have constraints at the time of adding a new view, still, new constraints will have to be added for it.